# Batch File that copies/pastes uniquely named file among other unique files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, unique

I have a folder that has multiple zip files in it. They are all uniquely named with a time-stamp (YYYYMMDDTTTTTT) after the database name (Database2). The end of the file name has Full or Log. Example of names:

```
Database2-20180201010002-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Full.zip
Database2-20180201000028-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Log.zip
Database2-20180131000021-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Full.zip
Database2-20180131000042-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Log.zip
Database2-20180130000017-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Full.zip
Database2-20180130000008-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Full.zip
```

---

I am looking at having a batch file that copies the current day's "Full" zip file and pastes it into a different folder.

> Database2-20180201010002-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Full.zip

I'm not sure how to search for 2 different parts of the file name. It also should be noted that the time part of the time stamp is completely random.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: move Database2-20180201*-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Full.zip C:\somefolder\

Comment: @Squashman How would I deal with the date being changed day-to-day? I'm wanting to have this batch automatically run daily. Tomorrow it would be Database2-20180202, then Database2-20180203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a FOR /F command to capture the output of the WMIC command to get the date assigned to a variable in a standard format.  You can then use that variable and wildcard characters to copy or move the file.

```
@echo off
REM Get todays date
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

REM set year month and day to a variable.
set yyyymmdd=%dt:~0,8%

move "Database2-%yyyymmdd%*-(94ea0-0183-4722-93-4ce2a1fz54)-Full.zip" "C:\somefolder\"
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much! Just a note: there is a typo in your last line. You only have 3 y's instead of 4. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already selected an answer. This can also be done in PowerShell. When you are confident that the correct files will be moved, remove the `-WhatIf` at the end.

```
Move-Item -Path $('.\Database2-'+$(Get-Date -f 'yyyyMMdd')+'*-Full.zip') -Destination '..\mt2\' -WhatIf
```